# Where is the inittab file?

Tags: init

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10, and I've just joined the Linux world coming from OS X.
I'm learning about runlevels and the `rc` directory in `/etc/`, and everywhere (manuals, tutorials, etc) I'm reading about `inittab`. But I can't find it in my Ubuntu installation. Why? Does Ubuntu follow the runlevel model? How are `rc` and levels loaded without `inittab`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you do `man inittab` in your terminal, all shall be revealed:

```
   The  /etc/inittab  file was the configuration file used by the original
   System V init(8) daemon.

   The Upstart init(8) daemon does not use this file,  and  instead  reads
   its  configuration  from  files  in  /etc/init.   See  init(5) for more
   details.
```

Comment: Worth to note, in /usr/share/doc/upstart/README.Debian.gz there is some other info.

Comment: but upstart keep using /etc/rc.* ?

Comment: @nkint: upstart keep using /etc/rc.* for packages not aware of upstart

Comment: `No manual entry for inittab` on 16.04...  (he says, years later)

Comment: Aye, `apropos inittab` will give nothing, in 16.04 the closest bit of info in the OS itself left seems to be in `man runlevel`.

Answer (score 21):

**Back in the days** [the "**System-V**" init service](https://askubuntu.com/tags/sysv/info) was used in Ubuntu, and it used the `/etc/inittab` file.

**Some time ago** (around 2006) [the "**Upstart**" init service](https://askubuntu.com/tags/upstart/info) replaced SysV. During these days you could follow [the top answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/34310/197753) and use `man inittab` to get info on this change.

**At the time of writing** (e.g. for Ubuntu 16.04) [the "**systemd**" boot process](https://askubuntu.com/tags/systemd/info) is in use and there is no reference left to "inittab" (e.g. if you do `apropos inittab` you'll probably not find anything). Instead you could do `man runlevel` to get similar information.

Bottom line: the `/etc/inittab` file is nowhere, likely because you use a newer version for Ubuntu that has a different init service, e.g. systemd.

Answer (score 13):

While searching this in various forum, I got to know that /etc/inittab is not anymore used in debian distro.

It uses `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`

Comment: not present in Ubuntu 18.04 anymore

Answer (score 6):

No, it does not follow the runlevel model.  Ubuntu has moved away from sysV init to upstart instead.  The main reason for this was to parallelize the initialization process to vastly reduce boot time.

Comment: runlevels continue to exist, for what I know

Comment: It is not explicitly implemented by upstart, but it is supported:  http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#failure-modes

Answer (score 3):

As most of the answers here state, That Debian/Ubuntu have switched from sysV to systemd, and ***systemd*** has it's own way of managing the ***boot targets*** (which was called runlevels) here are the commands used to set the default or switching to another target provided by systemctl:

- `systemctl isolate` used to switch between targets

  - `systemctl isolate multi-user` switchs to the multi user target
  - `systemctl isolate graphical` switchs to the graphical interface target
- `systemctl get-default` outputs the current default target
- `systemctl set-default` changing the default boot target

  - `systemctl set-default multi-user` will set the default boot target to the multi user target and this will simple get done by creating a symlink `/etc/systemd/system/default.target` points to `/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target`
  - `systemctl set-default graphical` setting back the default boot target to the graphical interface
- Resources: [amazingly explained by *Shawn Powers* in this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/WMy3OzvBWc0?t=14069)