# Why I cannot find in /etc/inittab?

Tags: boot, init

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [where is inittab file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34308/where-is-inittab-file)

I have learned from the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process) that init is usually called by the kernel with an argument to specify the runlevel, in order to do different things according to different runlevel, and that runlevel can be found from `/etc/inittab`, but why I cannot find in `/etc/inittab`?

Comment: There's a [similar question and answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34308/where-is-inittab-file?rq=1) which might apply for your question as well.

Comment: Take a look at [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/). May help.

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu uses different runlevels than other Linux distros.

It also uses **rc*.d** instead of **inittab** ( * going from 0 to 6). Open `/etc/rcS.d/README` & `/etc/init.d/README` to know more.

Comment: Debian and derivatives use upstart ;)

Comment: Isn't it about time Ubuntu updates the `man boot` then?  (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man7/boot.7.html)

Comment: There are no README files in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

/etc/inittab is no longer used in Ubuntu. The configuration it provided for some services (such as TTYs) can be found in the upstart config. Runlevels as a concept has been made obsolete by this and has not been used for this in Ubuntu for quite a while now.