# How do I prevent a folder inside of /tmp from being cleaned up?

Tags: bash, 14.10, find

This question is about Ubuntu 14.10 on my developer laptop.

I've got a folder in `/tmp` that is used by an application to put temporary stuff in there. This application usually makes a temporary folder in my homedir and deletes it afterwards. For some reason that doesn't work when the homedir is encrypted. So instead, I made a symlink to `/tmp/foo` inside my homedir. My application can write there and make it's temporary subfolder.

Now `/tmp/foo` gets deleted every time I reboot my machine. Until now I've just recreated the folder manually after reboot. Now I learned in [How is the /tmp directory cleaned up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20783/how-is-the-tmp-directory-cleaned-up) that there is a job doing that.

I've looked at `/etc/init/mounted-tmp.conf` but my bashfu and especially my findfu are not sufficient to do what I want. Here's an excerpt from that file:

> ```
>    EXCEPT='! -name .
>             ! ( -path ./lost+found -uid 0 )
>             ! ( -path ./quota.user -uid 0 )
>             ! ( -path ./aquota.user -uid 0 )
>             ! ( -path ./quota.group -uid 0 )
>             ! ( -path ./aquota.group -uid 0 )
>             ! ( -path ./.journal -uid 0 )
>             ! ( -path ./.clean -uid 0 )
>             ! ( -path "./...security*" -uid 0 )'
>
>    # Remove all old files, then all empty directories
>    find . -depth -xdev $TEXPR $EXCEPT ! -type d -delete
>    find . -depth -xdev $DEXPR $EXCEPT -type d -empty -delete
> ```

What I want to do is add a condition that makes it delete everyting inside `/tmp/foo`, but not `/tmp/foo` itself. How do I do that?

Comment: Is `/tmp/foo` a directory or a file?

Comment: A directory. There are files inside.

Comment: Why not add `mkdir /tmp/foo` right before `end script`?

Comment: Just FYI (you may already know this): 14.10 reaches EOL in July 2015, so you should really upgrade to Vivid as soon as possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`/etc/init/mounted-tmp.conf` is part of the `mountall` package, so any updates on that package and the suggested changes will be reverted.

```
$ sudo dpkg -S /etc/init/mounted-tmp.conf 
mountall: /etc/init/mounted-tmp.conf
```

Instead, according to the [Filesystem Hierachy standard (FHS)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html);

Regarding [/tmp](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#PURPOSE17):

> Programs must not assume that any files or directories in /tmp are
>   preserved between invocations of the program.

Regarding [/var/tmp](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#PURPOSE50):

> The /var/tmp directory is made available for programs that require  temporary files or directories that are preserved between system reboots. 
>   Therefore, data stored in /var/tmp is more persistent than data in /tmp.

So you should change your symbolic link to use `/var/tmp` instead of `/tmp`.

Comment: Classic example of when you have a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

Comment: @WernerCD could you elaborate what you mean by that? Are you saying that `/var/tmp` is not a good idea?

Comment: [When all you have is a hammer...](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail) - `If a person is familiar with ... a certain, single instrument, they may have a confirmation bias to believe that it is the answer to/involved in everything.` I'm saying that the OP is using /tmp for something it's not meant to be used for - Using /tmp as a hammer to his problem of keeping tmp-but-not-quite-tmp stuff. /var/tmp is MEANT to be kept between reboots, so its the right answer.

Answer (score 8):

Not strictly an answer to your question, but you might find `/var/tmp` to be a more suitable location, as it doesn't get cleaned up over a reboot.  It's designed for temporary files that should not be automatically discarded after a short time.

What I often do, however, is create myself a folder under /opt to store random things I don't want in home.  That's a suitable place to put things that are outside the main OS's control.

Comment: This is the right idea. If /tmp doesn't do what you want, then store your info somewhere else - even on another drive if there's space available. Don't mess with things that Linux (and other programmers) expects to be a certain way unless it's the only way to get the result you need.

Answer (score 6):

Like so:

```
EXCEPT='! -name .
            ...
            ! ( -path "./foo" )'

   # Remove all old files, then all empty directories
   ...
   find /tmp/foo/* -depth -xdev $TEXPR -delete
```

Example:

```
$ cd /tmp/foo/
$ mkdir 1 2 3
$ touch 3 4 5
$ find /tmp/foo/* -depth -xdev $TEXPR -delete
$ ls /tmp/foo/
$
```

I do agree with user aap: You either should take care of this in the software used by re-creating the directory there if they are tmp files or use another directory if they are not tmp files that is not purged.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. While the `find` command works as expected when run manually, the directory is still removed after editing `/etc/init/mounted-tmp.conf`. It seems like there's something else going on here.

Comment: wth. ehm.  that should mean that the 1st line is faulty. maybe it needs to be relative(?)

Comment: @terdon yes seems it needs to be relative to /tmp/

Comment: I don't think so, I tried various permutations, including `-path ./foo` and even `-name '*foo*'` and none of them worked (on Ubuntu Server 14.04). I think that's just not the right file and we're looking in the wrong place. What you're suggesting _should_ work, it just doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to have files with future value, write to the /tmp directory (/var/tmp, as suggested by others, is a better place). That said, you might want to give a shot at chattr. This should be run after the application exits, but before a shutdown. Remember that this operation won't let *anything* write to that directory henceforth.

touch /tmp/foo/ddmmyy/.001_immute_me
chattr +i /tmp/foo/ddmmyy/.001_immute_me

Comment: How would that be useful if I want to have a temporary directory?

Answer (score -1):

Run this:

```
echo "if [ ! -e /etc/foo/ ]; then mkdir /etc/foo/; fi; rm -rf /etc/foo/*" > /bin/foodel; sudo chmod 755 /bin/foodel
```

then Add this to <strike>/etc/inittab</strike> see here: [where is inittab file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34308/where-is-inittab-file):

```
foo:2345:boot:/bin/foodel
```

That will create /etc/foo on boot if it doesn't exist, and then empty it.

This will do the same on bash login:

```
echo "/bin/foodel" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Ubuntu version 14 doesn't use `/etc/inittab`.  This is clearly and unequivocally stated on its manual page.

Comment: \*facepalm\* Sorry @JdeBP, this is what happens to me after juggling 4 different versions of linux.  He can put the code somewhere stated http://askubuntu.com/questions/34308/where-is-inittab-file